# Finding a derivative of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives

I am trying to compute the derivative of the following series.

Define:
$$ u_n=\frac{1}{n^2}e^{-n^2x^2}\,\,x\in R $$
and 
$$u=\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n$$

Then I am trying to compute $u'$. Any helps? Note that the summation of derivative of $u_n$ is not convergence uniformly.

I ask a question related to this before, it might be helpful to look at [it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/969566/show-a-series-is-not-convergence-uniformly)

Answer (score 0):

If
$f(x)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}e^{-n^2x^2}
$,
then
$f'(x)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} -e^{-n^2x^2}
$.

This is related to the
theta functions,
one of which is
$\theta_3(q)
=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} q^{n^2}
$
where
$|q| < 1$.

Comment: Ha? Can you be more specific?... I don't know theta functions...

Comment: Just do a search for "theta functions" and you will find many references.

Comment: The derived series does not converge for $x = 0$. It's probably worth a mention.